# Sql OpenJson - Incorrect syntax near '$.recordtype'

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which i'm going to execute and the function of this is it will insert the json result in my table "ItemTransaction". Then i'm going to retrieve it by declaring variable which the JsonString. the problem is i cannot execute my stored procedure.

Incorrect syntax near '$.recordtype'.

I don't know which exactly the error.

```
exec AWSLINK.APILINK.dbo.spu_JsonSendData 'LoadItem',@pBranchCode,@pTranNo,'','','Test','POST'

        Declare @JsonString varchar(MAX) = (Select DataReceived from AWSLINK.APILINK.dbo.ItemTransaction where 
                                DocType ='LoadItem' and BranchCode = @pBranchCode and TranNo =  @pTranNo)

            SELECT * FROM  
            OPENJSON ( @JsonString,'$."records"')  
            WITH (   
                          RecordType   varchar(200) '$.recordtype' ,  
                          ItemID     varchar     '$.id',  
                          ItemDetails varchar(200) '$.itemid',  
                          Quantity int          '$.locationquantityonhand'  
             )
```

Comment: Why not output the JSON using an output variable in the procedure?

Comment: @SteveC what do you mean ?

Comment: What is the definition of your Stored Procedure? The code you have posted looks "fine". Give us a [mre].

Comment: @Larnu, yes it looks fine but when i add that code shown above.
when i try to save / execute , it can't be . the error shown above also.

Comment: Add what code? YOu say the `EXEC` statement is failing, however we can't know what the SQL is inside that Procedure (`spu_JsonSendData`), and without a [mre] then we have no idea why SQL that we can't see is failing. Don't forget, we don't (and should not) have access to your SQL instance so you need to provide *all* the needed information. If a Procedure is failing then that means you *need* to provide the definition for said procedure, and likely sample data and sample parameters so that we can run said procedure.

Comment: @Larnu the OP doesn't say the EXEC statement is failing.  He says when he adds the code below the procedure then the batch doesn't run.  The error occurs after the DECLARE which would execute prior to the query.

Comment: Can you share your @JsonString value?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
drop proc if exists dbo.TestExample;
go
create proc dbo.TestExample
  @var1             int,
  @json             nvarchar(max) output
as
set nocount on;
select @json=(select @var1 var1 for json path, without_array_wrapper);
go

declare
  @out_json          nvarchar(max);

exec dbo.TestExample 1, @json=@out_json output;
print (@out_json);
```

Output:
{"var1":1}